# How to display video, get & managing sound channels of a stream video in android?

Tags: android, audio

I have a mpeg-dash video in this URL : http://mediaserver01.heartscreation.co.jp/Dash2/John_Test/John_Test.mpd

This video is including 4 smaller screens, similar to :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBEcfn6V6ZQ

Now I wanna know how to:

1. Crop & display these 4 screen separately in android.
2. Split video's sound to 6 channels: left volume, right volume, guitar sound, vocal sound, drum sound, bass sound, and allow to mute/change volume for each channel.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Does anyone know? Or it's impossible?

Comment: @fadden do you know something about one of my problems? I will be really grateful if you can help!

Comment: @Bao Le do you know something about one of my problems? I will be really grateful if you can help!